# Received NaN for the `className` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am working with a React project and I was trying to add a content after I clicked on a link to show that it's active, but it keeps popping out that bug. Is there any way I can fix this?

This is my code below:

```
const activeClassName =
  'relative before:content-[' *
  '] before:-top-4 before:left-1/2 before:-ml-1 before:absolute before:text-amber-400'
```

Comment: what is that `*`?

Comment: `NaN` stands for "not a number". In this case is caused by trying to multiply two strings with the `*` (multiplication operator).

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` is a logical output for your code which is "*" multiplication of a string
the output is `NaN` because string is not a number
Change * to be +

Answer (score 1):

You are closing your string using the single-quote in your `content` utility-class and then reopening the string after the asterisk. It should work if you replace one set of quotes with double-quotes. For example:

```js
const activeClassName =
  'relative before:content-[" * "] before:-top-4 before:left-1/2 before:-ml-1 before:absolute before:text-amber-400'
```